# How to Query a String in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently practicing pandas

I am using some pokemon data as a practice https://gist.github.com/armgilles/194bcff35001e7eb53a2a8b441e8b2c6

i want to make a program that allows the user to input their queries and I will return the result that they need.

since i do not know how many parameters the user will input, i just made some code that will break that up and then put it in the format that pandas can understand, but when i am trying to execute my code, it just returns None.

whats wrong with my code?

thank you

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'PATH HERE')
column_heads = df.columns
print(f'''
This is a basic searcher

Input your search query as follows:
<Head1>:<Value1>, <Head2>:<Value2> etc..

Example: 
Type 1:Bug,Type2:Steel,Legendary:False

Heads:
{column_heads}

''')


usr_inp = input('Enter Query: ')
queries = usr_inp.split(',')
parameters = {}
for query in queries:
    head, value = query.split(':')
    parameters[head] = value

print('Your search parameters:', parameters)

df_query = 'df.loc['
for key,value in parameters.items():
    df_query += f'''(df['{key}'] == '{value}')&'''


df_query = df_query[:-1] + ']'

exec('''print(exec(df_query))''')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use `exec` or `eval`—though, if you must, you should use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) instead of exec, as in `print(eval(df_query))`; `eval` will return the value of the expression (i.e. the result of the query), while `exec` just executes a statement, returning `None`.

You could do something like

```py
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

df[reduce(np.logical_and, (df[col] == val for col, val in parameters.items()))]
```

Step by step:

1. Collect a list of "conditions" (boolean Series) of the form `df[column] == value`, given the search query parameters:

   ```py
   conditions = [df[column] == value for column, value in parameters.items()]
   ```
2. Combine all conditions together using the `and` operator. With pandas Series/numpy arrays, this is done with the bitwise `&` operator, which is represented by the binary function `operator.and_` (`operator` is a module in the Python standard library). `reduce` just means applying a binary operator to the first pair of elements, then to the result of that and the third element, and so on, until you only have one element; so, in this particular case: `conditions[0] & conditions[1]`, `(conditions[0] & conditions[1]) & conditions[2]`, etc.

   ```py
   mask = reduce(operator.and_, conditions)
   ```

   Alternatively, it might be clearer (and less error-prone) to use `np.logical_and`, which represents the "proper" boolean `and` operation:

   ```py
   mask = reduce(np.logical_and, conditions)
   ```
3. Index the dataframe with the combined mask:

   ```py
   df[mask]
   ```

Comment: is there also a way that i can do to search for values in the range using also this technique. 

for example i want to search for fire types with HP in the range 50-100.

thanks

Comment: Yes, you would just need to extend the parsing to allow a range query (how you want to do that is up to you) and modify the list of conditions (step 1 above), so that the conditions are of the form `lo <= df[column] <= hi`.